# SSHD failing - reading speeds under 100 Kb/s

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery

My old Seagate SSHD (ST1000DX001) started responding slower.  I've been trying to backup important files from it to a newly bought SSD and the reading speeds are under 100 Kb/s which often breaks to 0 Kb/s while 'Active Time' value is at 100% (Windows 10 Task Manager - Performance).

While initially I've been using regular copy/paste, I built a C# app to do this, hoping to get better results.
Now here is the strange part. After I've been copying the files via the C# script, those copied files can now be read/copied without issues, at higher speeds.
Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: Also, how full are both disks? How about overprovisioning? Do you still have room to turn around or is your drive near the end of the line? When's the last time you've optimized the SSD?

Answer (score 0):

On second read, the files are found inside the Windows cache, which is in memory.

No read is required from the disk if the files are already in memory.
Therefore the second read is done at the speed of memory, which is
very fast.